# Delete notification after button is pressed in android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0

Until Android Q (i.e. Android 10), to delete my notification after a button notification was pressed I used a broadcast receiver, so I used `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method. From the receiver I deleted the notification and I called `startActivity()`. Now with Android 10 it's no more possible to call `startActivity` from background, so what's the best approach in this case? To be noted that the activity to be launched is a system activity or in general an activity without direct control (otherwise it would be easy to delete the notification from there).

Comment: Hmmm... you may need to launch your own no-UI activity (`Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`) instead of some other activity from the `Notification`. In the no-UI activity, you would clear the notification, start the actual activity that you want, and `finish()` the no-UI activity (so it is not on the back stack).

Comment: Have you tested that on Q, and found that it's not working? Quoting [Restrictions to background activity starts: Conditions that allow for activity starts](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts#conditions-allow-activity-starts) – "The app receives a notification `PendingIntent` from the system. In the case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is sent."

Comment: I used a NoDisplay activity at the moment. @Mike it doesn't work for me too at least on the emulator and as usual docs is totally useless, it says "few seconds" what the hell does it means? Bah.